# How to get access code along from Facebook which manually building a Login Flow

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, facebook-access-token

I am trying to [manually build a login flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.0), so that the our users are able to login to our website with their Facebook accout.

Anyhow, I am getting stuck at the step of "Confirming identity" where I have passed the code I have received with the use of `$_GET["code"]` to get the `access_token` with the url

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={app-id}&redirect_uri={redirect-uri}&client_secret={app-secret}&code={code-parameter}
```

On visiting this url, I am able to see the access_code and the expire. Anyhow, what I want to do is to have the program visit the page and then copy the entire contents (or just the access_code part) into a variable in the php code.

I have tried this:

```
$access_token = readfile("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=834481703238074&redirect_uri=http://example.co/app.php&client_secret={secret_code}&code=$code");
```

But it's not working. What should I do? What is the right way to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm confused. First you said- *I am able to see the access_code and the expire* , then you said *it's not working*? What's the problem?

Comment: @SahilMittal I am able to see the access_code and expire when I manually visit the unique url generated by facebook. What I want is for the php program to visit it without displaying on the screeen and then save the two codes seperately as variables.

Answer (score 0):

Of what I understood from the question, you are simply looking to get the **access token** from the access token url. (correct me if I'm wrong)

To do this-

```
$response = file_get_contents($token_url);
$params = null;
parse_str($response, $params);
$access_token = $params['access_token'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created this PHP function, you can use it:

```
function getAccessToken($app_id, $secret, $base_url, $code) {
    $ch = curl_init();
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/oauth/access_token?'. 'client_id=' . $app_id . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($base_url) . '&client_secret=' . $secret . '&code=' . $code);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $r  = curl_exec($ch);
    $r = strstr(str_replace('access_token=', '', $r), '&expires=', true);
    return $r;
}
```

it return the `access_token` string, just pass `app_id`, `app_secret`, `redirect_uri` & `code` from `$_GET['code']`

You might be wondering why am I using `strstr()` along with `str_replace()` that's because the header of `/oauth/access_token` is `text/plain` instead of `JSON`, keep in mind, this `access_token` lasts for 2 hours at maximum, you can extend it to last for 60 days